Any one know how return 0 works or maybe any problem with devc++
im new at coding.
so right now im learning C and im using devc++.
but i don't know my program instantly close after i compile
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    
    printf("hello");
    
    return 0;
}

here is my code, i tried getch(); and it works but i'm curios why return 0; not working ?
from what i read at book return 0 should be make the program pause or wait us to click any key to close the programe.
please for the guide.

from what i read at book return 0 should be make the program pause or wait us to click any key to close the programe. It doesn't.

The behavior you describe is not part of your program, but the development environment you're running in. Visual Studio typically have that behavior.

but im not using vscode, you guys know how to make return 0 works without getch, pause or etc ?

It's not a behavior of the return 0; statement or your program. It has nothing to do with the C language at all. It's the behavior of the development environment only. If the development environment doesn't have a setting to change that behavior, you need to explicitly add something like that into your program. Or change the environment (which you should do anyway, DevC++ is old and unmaintained and obsolete, there are many much better out there, even free).

Aside:  A long time ago DOS definitely inspected the value returned by main() and squawked if it was non-zero, bugged you with a message and a key press to make sure you knew.

The point here is that when you run the program it does print “hello” but devc++ immediately closes the terminal since the program has finished execution. But when you use getch() it waits for a character input from user, so until you press any key on your keyboard it wont continue the full execution. This behaviour has nothing to do with return 0.
You can try using vscode and it’s terminal. It wont close the terminal and retain the outputs after execution.

Jayendra's information is good. Let me give a bit more information. return 0 exits the C function that's running. In your case, the function is main(), so exiting that function with value 0 exits the whole program with a successful status. Then, as Jayendra explained, the devc++ terminal screen closes, so you can't see the program's results any more.
You can also start up a command tool and run your program. I don't know where devc++ puts its compiled executable, so you'll have to find it. Once you find it, you can run a normal command tool, "cd" to that directory, and run it. Then you'll see the program output.
One final suggestion. Change the printf as follows:
printf("hello\n");

The '\n' (newline) puts the "hello" on a line of its own.
